# Why is repulsion the true test of Electrification and not attraction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, charge, coulombs-law

[image]
Please explain the answer by using both experimental and logical methods.

Comment: You know ... attraction may be cause of induction (which is unwanted) ...

Answer (score 3):

Charge can only be tested with a "test charge".

If one takes a test charge, for example on a pendulum, positive or negative, to test if an object is charged, and the pendulum is attracted , the effect might be just because the charge of the test charge induced the opposite charge on the object's surface.

> The interaction between two like-charged objects is repulsive. The interaction between two oppositely charged objects is attractive. What type of interaction is observed between a charged object and a neutral object? The answer is quite surprising to many students of physics. Any charged object - whether positively charged or negatively charged - will have an attractive interaction with a neutral object. Positively charged objects and neutral objects attract each other; and negatively charged objects and neutral objects attract each other.

....

> Any charged object - plastic, rubber, or aluminum - will exert an attractive force upon a neutral object. And in accordance with Newton's law of action-reaction, the neutral object attracts the charged object.

This is because all neutral objects are composed of atoms , and the outer layer of atoms is negatively charged.

If a positive test charge comes near the surface, the electrons are attracted and the test charge moves towards the surface. If a negative charge nears the surface the electrons are pushed away and this leaves a window in space  for the positive charged nuclei of the atoms  , to attract the test charge. So one cannot decide *definitely* if the surface is charged, because of this interaction. Attraction gives no  answer.

If the test charge is repulsed, one has to try with a positive and a negative test charge, but once repulsion is established, then it is sure that the surface of the object is charged with a like charge.